.env type issue in Typescript , Nodejs server
I am trying to use my environment variables in my nodejs server written in typescript. I am requiring type string but .env variables are of type string|undefined. Is there any way to fix type of .env variables.
i have type assertion on .env variables like this :
process.env.Variable as string
It didn't work, and I am still getting this type as string|undefined.

It's not possible for the type of that line to be considered undefined. Please show the complete code, the full error message and the exact line where it points to.

I am using Firebase credentials, so firebase expects string. so I used like this projectId: process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID ,  and the error I am getting is this
 throw new error_1.FirebaseAppError(error_1.AppErrorCodes.INVALID_CREDENTIAL, errorMessage);                   ^ FirebaseAppError: Service account object must contain a string "project_id" property. @GuyIncognito

Read the error message very carefully. Does the object have a "project_id" property?

"I used like this projectId:..." looks like a simple typo then. You're supplying projectId but the SDK expects project_id

That is firebase type issue which is not fixed, the firebase credential contains property in this format project_id, but if I write like this then I get error message Object literal may only specify known properties, but 'project_id' does not exist in type 'ServiceAccount'. Did you mean to write 'projectId'? so I searched and got that we have to use camelcase for this. @GuyIncognito

The issue is either a) the object is structured wrong or b) you're passing an undefined value (env variable is not set.) The error thrown is not a Typescript error so Typescript types is not the root cause. If the value is actually undefined then no amount of type casting etc. is going to magically assign a correct value into it.

Since there are no guarantee that you have this variable in runtime, TypeScript forces you to actually check the type of the variable. Best way is to either use type predicate or assertion function, depending on your requirements. If you want to fail, you can use built-in assert module from Node:
import assert from 'node:assert';

assert(typeof process.env.Variable === "string");

// Here process.env.Variable will be string

Playground link
You can also write your own assertion function.
function assertVariableIsString(arg: string | undefined, message = "Variable should be string"): asserts arg is string {
  if (typeof arg !== "string") throw new Error(message);
}

assertVariableIsString(process.env.Variable);

// Here process.env.Variable will be string


assertion is only used for checking, you cant directly manipulate types, I want to know that is there any way that we can define or directly change env variable type. @Mr.Hedgehog

If you assign it a value manually, it will be string or undefined according to value you are assigning. If you are just reading a value that should be there, you have to check it's type.

Usually I was performing a pre-check if the env var exists at all:
if(!process.env.Variable) throw new Error('Variable is not provided');

After that the type will change from string|undefined to string;
Or you could use some default value if it is applicable to your case, something like:
const foo = process.env.Variable || 'default';

